# Sort an IList<T> in place

Tags: c#, .net, list, ilist, in-place

If I have a `List<T>`, I can sort it in place using for example

```
myList.Sort((x,y) => x.MyComparisonMethod(y));
```

If I have an `IList<T>`, I can sort it into a new list using

```
var sortedIList = unsortedIList.OrderBy(x => x.SortingValue);
```

**How can I sort an `IList<T>` in place?**

I am using C# .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What situation are you in that `unsortedIList = unsortedIList.OrderBy(x => x.SortingValue);` won't solve?

Comment: _" I can sort it into a new list using"_ no, that's not the case, `OrderBy` doesnt return a list, you have to call `ToList` to create a new list. Is your question how to use `List.Sort` with an `IList<T>` instead of a `List<T>`?

Comment: You'll have to create a `Sort` method and use it. Take one of those used by Mono for example.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own extension method using [ArrayList.Adapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.adapter(v=vs.110).aspx) as `IList<T>` wrapper and your own `CustomComparer` starting from some [Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate:

```
public static class IListExtensions
{
    public static void Sort<T>(this IList<T> list, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        ArrayList.Adapter((IList)list).Sort(new CustomComparer<T>(comparison));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the -1? What's the purpose of a -1 without explanation?

Comment: I actually like this, but couldn't find `CustomComparer` in the framework.  Instead I used `Comparer<T>.Create(comparison)` which seems to do what is intended here.

Answer (score -1):

*" I can sort it into a new list using"* no, that's not the case, `OrderBy` doesnt return a list, you have to call `ToList` to create a new list. Is your question how to use `List.Sort` with an `IList<T>` instead of a `List<T>`?

You can write an extension method for `IList<T>`:

```
public static IList<T> Sort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var seqList = sequence as List<T>;
    if (seqList != null)
    {
        seqList.Sort((IComparer<T>)comparer);
        return seqList;
    }

    var seqArray = sequence as T[];
    if (seqArray != null)
    {
        Array.Sort(seqArray, (IComparer<T>)comparer);
        return seqArray;
    }

    return sequence.OrderBy(t => t, (IComparer<T>)comparer).ToList();
}
```

Now you can use `Sort` on lists, arrays or any other kind of sequence:

```
IList<string> strings = new[] { "B", "A", "C" };
strings.Sort();
```

**Update**: if you just want one for arrays or lists you can use:

```
public static void Sort<T>(this IList<T> sequence, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var seqList = sequence as List<T>;
    if (seqList != null)
    {
        seqList.Sort((IComparer<T>)comparer);
        return;
    }

    var seqArray = sequence as T[];
    if (seqArray != null)
    {
        Array.Sort(seqArray, (IComparer<T>)comparer);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have slightly confusing behaviour.  It sorts in place for `List<T>` and `T[]`, but it returns a new list for anything else.

Comment: @CharlesMager: you could make the parameter an `IList<T>` and remove `return sequence.OrderBy(t => t, (IComparer<T>)comparer).ToList()` if you don't want that. I just wanted to include it because OP has mentioned it. It's the all-inclusive approach. The return value is also redundant then.

Comment: Then you'd have the 'not all code paths return a value' problem as `IList<T> != List<T>` - which is the crux of the question, really.  How do you sort an `IList<T>` in place when it might not be `List<T>`?

Comment: @CharlesMager: why? If you want one just for `IList<T>` you can make the method `void`. Both, lists and arrays support the void method `Sort`. Edited my answer to show it.

Comment: ah, yes.  Being a bit dumb there... but the point still stands that if it isn't `T[]` or `List<T>` it won't do any sorting.  What if I passed in `Collection<T>`, `BindingList<T>` etc?

Comment: @CharlesMager: first you were complainig that the method does too much now that it does too little. OP seems to want only one that supports `IList<T>` and sorts "in place", so without creating a new list.

Comment: Which is my point - this doesn't support `IList<T>`, it supports 2 implementations of it.  I'm not deliberately trying to be argumentative, I just don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @CharlesMager: sorry, i'm hard of understanding today. It accepts an `IList<T>` which could f.e. be a `List<string>` or a `string[]` and it sorts them in place. What else could it support when OP asks "How can I sort an IList<T> in place"? It does not support an `IList`, that's right. But that wasn't asked.

Comment: But it could also be a `Collection<T>`, `BindingList<T>`, `ObservableCollection<T>`, any other of the dozens of implementations of `IList<T>` in the BCL, or a custom implementation.  These won't be sorted, but the contract implies they would.  Apologies if I'm sounding argumentative, as I don't have a solution short of 'implement sort yourself'.

Comment: @CharlesMager: you cannot support all since those collections don't support sorting by default. What you could do is to throw a  `NotSupportedException` at runtime if the type is not a list or array. But again,  that wasn't asked anyway. If you need to support it the easiest way is to use LINQ. For example: `new BindingList<T>(seqColl.OrderBy(x => x, comparer).ToList())`

Comment: I'm still struggling to see how you claim it's not asked - the question is literally *"How can I sort an IList<T> in place?"* - there's no mention it's limited to any specific implementations.  There are lots of generic solutions in the duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect you're referring to the fact that your `OrderBy` won't compile. That's because it returns an `IOrderedEnumerable`, which is not an `IList`, you'd have to perform `ToList()` afterwards to convert it back to an `IList` implementation:

```
var sortedIList = unsortedIList.OrderBy(x => x.SortingValue).ToList();
```

And if you want to use your own `IComparer`:

```
var sortedIList = unsortedIList.OrderBy(x => x.SortingValue, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as it isn't sorting the `unsortedIList` *in place*